# Android 2D game engine with canvas capability

Tags: android, 2d, android-canvas, draw, game-engine

Im looking for Android 2D framework which allows me to create canvas layer on which I can draw simple shapes like rect, oval atc (raster graphics). The canvas have to PERSIST everything I draw on it.

I found many engines (libgdx, andengine ...) but if they have capability to draw shapes, its only for one screen update. Reason becouse I dont store drawn shapes to some kind of List is becouse in app, the drawing occurs every screen update so I just want to modify canvas and dont remember anything.

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, android doesn't support something like that. Android uses double-buffering which means 2 alternatives "screens" that alternate each other so if you draw on one the next would be on random state.

There are tricks you can use to achieve what you want like draw both screens and then stop drawing, but android doesn't support such behavior because when you get hold of a canvas it's not certain that it returned exactly as what you did last frame, it doesn't specify what could cause an error, but if you ask me it could be anything that pops up on screen.

You don't really need an engine to do that, you can use a `SurfaceView` and draw on it (it supports shapes like the ones you want)